# Selenium Python Automation on Chrome browser

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Selenium to automate a web application. The language used is Python. 
Below is the scenario for which I am not able to work on a solution:

I am in a page where I have to click a button which will take me to another page. I have 14 other items of this type. Now the button property is the same for all 14 items. Each time I try to identify the buttons I see that their XPath is the same.

My question is which would be the best way to identify these buttons.

Once I identify them, I would need them to be clicked 14 times for different scenarios.

Here is the script I tried that fails:

```
List<WebElement> xyz = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('i.fa icon-launch')
xyz.__getitem__(0).click()
print(xyz)
```

I tried XPath, element, but none worked.

When I tried above I got an error like this:

```
xyz.__getitem__(0).click()
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The same error appears for all the 14 buttons on the screen.